# Problem with aurigma image uploader in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, aurigma

I am using Aurigma image uploader for uploading multiple images in asp.net

i am facing a problem in aurigma image uploader when i upload images it will show error

"Thumbnails of size more than 3 MPixels are not supported in standard version of image uploader."

But this is working fine in Mozilla or other browsers. this problem is occured only with (IE6/7/8).

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you are using *professional* license key for java uploader (i.e. for Mozilla and others) and *standard* for ActiveX (IE 6/7/8).

Anyway, you should contact [Aurigma support](http://www.aurigma.com/Support/) for details.